# Are my windows cat safe?

Tags: cats, safety, containment

I recently moved into the top floor of a 5 story building and wish to get two kittens soon. During the day the flat gets warm and we open the Windows a lot, so I'm worried that it might fall out of one of them.

[image]
Bedroom,

Bottom windows are opened as far as they normally go (can open wider, but that requires extra steps and is intended for cleaning only.

Top Windows open straight up, similar to the ones in the next image

No ledge, there's a drop straight down onto grass.

[image]

Kitchen/Living Room

Bottom window does not open at all.

Roof continues at the same angle (about 45 degrees) for about 1 or 2 more meters as the flat below us has the same angle for their windows. (Shown in the next image)

The top window starts at roughly chest height for me as a somewhat tall adult (190 cm/ 6"2).

[image]

Different perspective for image 2.

[image]

Map

Flat starts/ends at the red line, below that the roof continues to the next flat at the same angle of about 45 degrees

[image]

Living Room

3 Windows don't open. (At the pillars)
4 Windows open like regular windows, (2 left and 2 right)

There's a small ledge/windowsill outside with a width of about 30cm, beyond that the roof is angled at about 45 degrees for about 1 or 2 meters, see previous photo for a better look.

[image]

Roof with windowsill

[image]

roof.

If it's not already safe, what can I do to make it so?

Perhapt it would be better to get them during a colder season where we don't open the window as much?

Comment: Great pics by the way, they really help the reader understand your dilemma!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the first picture shows the windows opening at an angle from the top, these seem the safest, but the others seem like a major danger. If a cat can fit its head through the opening, the rest of its body can fit and follow. If you're getting kittens, the space their head can fit through is then smaller. Cats can jump quite high too, up to 8 feet (around 2.4 m) to be exact.

The time of year won't matter, simply because you'll have to come up with a fix next spring/summer anyways.

There are solutions though. There are mesh screens called window guards you can purchase, made to make windows kid-safe. They're made so children can't get to the window and to prevent falling or any other disasters. You could install indoor shutters (yes there is such a thing). Shutters may be the most decorative or look more liveable. There are actual "pet window screens" that are available online, I've never seen them in stores. And lastly you can make your own: purchase mesh and commercial grade Velcro - the kind that has 20lb (around 9 kg) test, so that if your kittens/cats jump or climb on it can hold the weight - if you use enough Velcro to fully line the inside of the window frame, and sew the mesh with also a high test strong thread, I would see this working well.

If you add a jingle bell, small "cow bell" or chimes sewn somewhere on each mesh screen (whether purchased or homemade) ,the noise it makes if the kitties do try to climb it will deter them from jumping up again.

Comment: Good answer. This apartment is not safe for kittens as it is